# Smallest cable for given wattages

Tags: high-voltage, wire, high-current

Hypothetically say I want to transfer different wattages: 5 W, 5 kW, 5 MW, 5 GW, 5 TW, 5 PW, 5 EW, on a power line.

Let's assume I have the ability to choose specific voltages and amps for each power line, and I want to minimize the size of the power line. I imagine there'd be a cross over point, where it makes more sense to isolate the wire to avoid sparking and arcs, rather than increasing the wire gauge (as it makes more sense to increase voltage rather than amperage).

Is this point and known and set one, or are more vague approaches used to determine what kind of wire to utilize?

Comment: No, there's no vagueness here. Have you googled this?

Comment: Hi, yes I have. It seems that in the sub 5kw range, there are cases where amperage > voltage, where's this does not seem to be common at the higher power levels, however it seems high power transfers are usually done with air gapped power lines, I would however argue that an air gapped wire is very big, as the air around it would be considered part of the wire for my question. - I tried looking into wires with ceramic and plastic shielding, however I haven't found a lot of information in the high power domain.

Comment: SI units named after a person have their symbols capitalised but are lowercase when spelled out. 'V' for volt, 'A' for ampere, 'K' for kelvin, 'Ω' (capital omega) for ohm, 'W' for watt, etc. Meanwhile 'k' is for kilo and all multipliers above 'k' (1000) are capitalised. You can [edit] your question to fix it. SI standard also recommends a space between the numbers and the units. (We don't write "5bananas" but "5 bananas". So "5 kW" is correct.)

Comment: very high voltage insulated conductors tend to use something called XLPE, cross linked poly ethylene. As the voltage increases, so the wire diameter has to increase, to maintain the surface field below the insulation breakdown field by reducing the curvature. In air, partial breakdown is corona, in solid insulation it's 'treeing'.

Comment: In the real world, the monetary cost of distributing power ivery important. That includes the cost of the conductor and insulation materials, the space used, the power lost in transmission and the labor to construct. The cost of getting power from a battery to the far side of a product is far different from the cost of getting power from a generating station to the furthest user on the grid. There is not a huge percentage difference between a narrow path compared to a wider path across a country. Like any engineering problem the problem is solved step-by-step considering all specific details.